# what is the connection throughput of multiple clients accessing same Azure blob container?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

Is it the same as here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/scalability-targets-standard-account?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json
Maximum request rate per storage account: 20,000 requests per second. Is this same for multiple clients connecting?

Answer (score 1):

Your link points to the entire storage account limits (blob, file share, queue etc), for a specific blob, most likely you should consider [these limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#azure-blob-storage-limits).

```
Target request rate for a single blob   Up to 500 requests per second
```

Comment: Thank you comment @Taguada. The link you have specified only points to single blob. I am looking for limit on individual connections to different blobs.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I may help you if you describe what your are trying to do :) Sorry, but I didn't understand what you mean.